# How can I use a function variable in a .then?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have coded this:

```
 us.isConnected().then(function (msg) { er.msg = msg }, function (msg) { er.msg = msg });
 $interval(function () {
    us.isConnected().then(function (msg) { er.msg = msg }, function (msg) { er.msg = msg });
    }, 20 * 1000);
```

I would like to simplify it with a function like this:

```
function connectMessage(msg) {
    er.msg = msg;
}

  us.isConnected().then(connectMessage(msg), connectMessage(msg));
    $interval(function () {
       us.isConnected().then(connectMessage(msg), connectMessage(msg));
    }, 20 * 1000);
```

However this gives me an error:

Error   2   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Could not apply type '(promiseValue: any) => ng.IHttpPromise<{}>' to argument 1 which is of type 'void'.

Can someone give me advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error 2 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: Could not apply type '(promiseValue: any) => ng.IHttpPromise<{}>' to argument 1 which is of type 'void'.

The first argument to `then` needs to be a *function* so `connectMessage` and not *you calling the function* i.e. `connectMessage(er.msg)`

> I would like to simplify it

How is `us.isConnected().then(connectMessage(er.msg), function () { er.msg = "Cannot connect" });` simpler than `us.isConnected().then(null, function () { er.msg = "Cannot connect" });` But thats a seperate discussion :)

### Based on Update

Don't call the function yourself i.e. `connectMessage` instead of `connectMessage(msg)`:

```
function connectMessage(msg) {
    er.msg = msg;
}

us.isConnected().then(connectMessage, connectMessage);
  $interval(function () {
     us.isConnected().then(connectMessage, connectMessage);
}, 20 * 1000);
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the same function to call four times. It's actually related to a previous question you may not have seen. One I submitted about an hour ago.

Comment: I just updated my question to make it a bit clearer. Not sure if this makes a difference but this is in the constructor of my typescript. Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

what you can do is

```
function connectMessage(msg) {
    er.msg = msg;
}

var connect = function () {
   us.isConnected().then(connectMessage, connectMessage);
}

connect();

var interval = $interval(connect, 20 * 1000);

$scope.on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
});
```

three points to note

1. create function to avoid repeating `connectMessage`
2. create function to avoid repeating `us.isConnected()`
3. cancel the interval on $destroy, very important part